# How can we know if a sequence is pseudo random or true random?

Tags: random

Given a sequence (ex 1 4 3 5 3 6 .....) and its range (ex 1-10 ), knowing that it is generated from a "Random Generator".
How to know whether that "Random Generator" is pseudo random or true random (Assuming the sequence is infinite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, [you can't](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25). For one thing -- the only thing you can actually observe is a *finite* sequence of numbers. Every possible observed sequence will have a non-zero probability of occurring even if the sequence is genuinely random. You can observe 20 tails in a row and that is completely consistent with tossing a genuinely fair coin. Conversely, any finite sequence, no matter how random it looks, can be generated by a deterministic process.

Having said that, there are various statistical tests (most famously the [Diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) developed by George Marsaglia) which can be applied to a sequence. They can't certify a sequence as random or pseudorandom with certainty, but poorly designed pseudorandom number generators will do poorly on these tests. On the other hand, if a sequence does well on these tests then it will be more or less impossible (without knowing the source of the numbers) to tell if it came from a pseudorandom number generator or a genuinely random source. The entire *point* of 50+ years of research is to ensure that the answer to your question is effectively "No - you can't tell".

Answer (score 2):

To add to the well written answer of John, I would like to add a few remarks.

First, I do believe that out of every "Random Generator", as you name them, none of the random number that you'll get are truly random. Even further, we do not know a way to procude a true "random" sequence of number. The only true random that you can obtain comes from quantic particles as they are not determinist and can be considered at some extent as random. When you have a website or a program that gives you a random number, it comes from a determinist method, which could theoretically be deduced, if we knew all of the initial conditions. Some of the more "random" algorithms, for example, use the variation of the atmosthere as a way to produce a seemingly random result (see [this random generator](https://www.random.org/randomness/) for example). And yet, if we could get all of the parameters used on an instant T, you could theoretically "guess a random number".

What you can do though, if you do not recognise a pattern in your data, is to do a [statistical analysis](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/statistical-analysis) of your data. As John said, there are numerous methods to recognise a correlation between your random values, and you could get some informations about your data. You could use tools on many mathematical programming tools (Matlab, Maple for example ...) to try to analyse your data. But, in the end, you might never be able to tell with a full certainty the veracity of your results.

So, just like John said, **NO**, you can't.

Comment: This simply isn't true anymore. Many physical systems show absolute 100% true quantum indeterminacy, and many of them are or can be attached to your computer. All modern processors include a true randomness source and microcode for accessing it, usually a reverse-biased diode. Mobile devices have cameras--CCD or CMOS photodetectors that can be used. If you have neither of these, you can buy any number of plug-in devices with similar sources. Genuine, true, totally non-pseudo random numbers are readily available to everyone these days given the right hardware and software.